# Problem with fetching body of a restful api?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm learning how to properly fetch an API in javascript into my code, and I am having some issues retrieving specific parts of the body. Ideally, I want to save the setup and punchline part of the body to be saved into a variable to be used later.

I wrote this:

```
fetch("https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/random/joke", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "79142f2e8cmsh903cd5752a9ee77p1166f8jsnb9c812f77793"
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

which returns this:

```
{
{
  success: true,
  body: [
    {
      _id: "60dd3699212bcedc7b8720a1",
      setup: "I saw a poster today for a free concert for those working in public health. It said 'Frontline Only'...",
      punchline: "Weird. I would've thought they'd fill the whole venue.",
      type: "health",
      likes: [],
      author: { name: "unknown", id: null },
      approved: true,
      date: 1618108661,
      NSFW: false
    }
  ]
}
```

As stated above, my desire here is to save the setup and punchline of the joke to a variable to be posted separately. How should I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "a variable to be posted separately" what does "posted" mean? If you simply want to know how to access the setup and punchline properties, they are  `data.body[0].setup` and `data.body[0].punchline` within your last `then()` statement.

Comment: By posted, I mean saving the value into variable to be console logged. Sorry about the confusing wording. I've tried setting a variable to data.body[0].setup and data.body[0].punchline as the other person suggested, but when console logged, it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the variables for the data you wish to fetch before hand. As 'data.body' is an array, one element in length, we have to access it using data.body[0]. Then you can assign the variables using the names of the elements e.g 'body[0].setup'.

This should work! :-)

```
var setup;
var punchline;

var data = await fetch("https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/random/joke", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "79142f2e8cmsh903cd5752a9ee77p1166f8jsnb9c812f77793"
    }
})

setup = data.body[0].setup; 
punchline = data.body[0].punchline; 
console.log(data); 
console.log(setup); 
console.log(punchline);
```

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong on my end, but using your exact code, the program return undefined for both variable.

Comment: you can try using this way (i've changed the code) to use the await keyword, so it shouldn't move on until the data is there.

Comment: be careful I have just been banned from the website for issuing too many requests! And you could also declare and assign to your variable in one line at the bottom 'setup = data.body[0].setup;' etc

Comment: My free subscription of the API lasted 50 jokes, and the punchline and setup both count as individual jokes. Sadly, I can't test this anymore. Thank you anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is that fetch() is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous). So, code that appears in the program on a line *after* the fetch statement will execute *before* your then() statement. A simple example:

```
runsFirst();
fetch.then(() => runsThird());
runsSecond();
```

So when you attempt to log these values outside your then() statement, you are actually logging them before they've been set. To actually get the values, you need:

```js
var setup;
var punchline;

fetch("https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/random/joke", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "79142f2e8cmsh903cd5752a9ee77p1166f8jsnb9c812f77793"
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(function (data){
    //Logs data
    setup = data.body[0].setup; 
    punchline = data.body[0].punchline; 
    console.log(setup, punchline); 
});

//Logs undefined
console.log(setup, punchline);
```

If you find this syntax confusing, you can use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), and then lines will more or less execute in the order they are written, though the browser support is not quite as good.

Comment: My subscription to the dad joke expired just now, I will try to use your logic/code to apply to a different API, thanks!